# The 「上がれる」 in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, potential-form

Taken from 「イエスタデイをうたって２」

Context: One guy wants to visit a female friend (who he barely knows) while she is sick. This is their conversation when he suddenly stops before entering her house:

> 「一人暮らしの女の部屋にそう　ほいほいと**上がれる**か？」
>
> 「シナコ先生の部屋には入ったくせに？」
>
> 「あいつんとこはいーの...」

As intended in the title of this question, what puzzles me about this conversation is the 「**上がれる**」. I get what their conversation is about, however I am unsure about what this part of the sentence means in a literal way. Is he asking her if she really wants to let other people enter her room/house so easily? Is the 「**上がれる**」simply passive?

I feel like overseeing something about the sentence and twisting the meaning to fit what I had in my head already.

(Further context: The girl actually has a love interest in the guy (what he knows about); however he is in love with シナコ先生, who is an acquaintance of both. The girl speaking in this conversation knows that he visited シナコ a few days ago and cared for her while she was sick.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

上がれる here is the potential form / 可能形 of 上がる.

> そうほいほいと上がれるか？
> Could I ever enter so easily/casually? Would I ever be allowed to / Would it ever be possible to enter so easily/casually?

The passive form / 受身形 of [上]{あ}がる is [上]{あ}が**ら**れる.

He's saying he doubts a man would be allowed to enter the room of a woman living alone so easily/casually, from a moralistic viewpoint, and hesitating to do so.